# Meaning of the word "Hepp"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

While playing a game I found quite a strange word "Hepp". This response is pronounced when you are given money or ammo. I tried to find this word in dictionaries, but my search wasn't successful. I found this word on Duden, but it just says that it's an interjection, and there is no definition at all. I think it might be some encouraging word. If there's the same word in English, could you tell me it?

Comment: What "game" was this? While it is partly just what you present here, it is also ['a bit tainted'…](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hep-Hep_riots). Please clear that up.

Comment: It was BioShock Infinite. I've already looked through this article before, but there's no connection with my word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is an interjection, the meaning of "Hepp" is heavily reliant on the context it is used in. I assume you are "thrown" the weapon or money in the game, and "Hepp!" would be an appropriate thing to say when you are throwing/passing someone an item. The function of the word in this context is to draw attention to the action, as opposed to just throwing something at someone without any words.

Additionally, I have also seen "Hepp!" used as an expression of excertion during a strenuous throwing act. E.g. "The farmer yelled "Hepp!" as he hived the wooden logs on the pyre."

Based on @Asmus's comment below, I decided to update this answer:
"Heb!" the imperative of the verb "[heben](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heben#Etymology)" (i.e. to lift or to heave) is a plausible source of the expression "Hepp!". Based on my experience, "Hepp!" is commonly used to coordinate efforts between multiple people when lifting, catching or holding things.

Comment: I assume that "Hepp" comes from heavy works, that need coordination for all people who help. Like lifting heavy things up and all need to lift at the same time. So one of the workers say "Hepp --- Hepp --- Hepp" in regular time steps.

Comment: @Allerleirauh perhaps it's reasonable to assume that it is a contracted form of "heben" [lifting], perhaps given as an imperative, i.e. "heb!" [lift]. Similarly, we also have the interjection "Hopp!" which derives from "hüpfen" [jumping], as in "let's‚ go!".

Comment: Interesting hypothesis @Allerleirauh. When I served as a pioneer in the Bundesheer, there were indeed [drill commands](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kommandosprache) for heavy work. Among them: _Eeeeeer - hebt!_ for lifting objects in a group.

Comment: In conclusion, I would like to say that @Asmus was right, and it was just the word "heben" in the imperative mood. I've downloaded the English version, and I heard that she says, "Ammo! Take it!". Thanks, everyone, for your help.

Comment: I'll pressume that it patterns with *geben*, *gib!*. The vowel quality differs, but the quantity is short in both cases, and *hib* could become *hepp* through Auslautverhärtung and Schwa (or Schwebelaut). I'm not sure about the initial, would like to see a *W-* for it to relate to weap-ons directly (cp. *alarma* "get weapons!" on the one hand, consider that *help, Hilfe* has no known origin. Oh, sorry, I like to waffle).